# Get Data from class to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

> I am trying to get the allPaths variable to the Controller so that I can download the files from the db.
>   **Here is the class:**

```
public class DBQueries 
{


    public List<string> GetSpecificYears(string[] response)
    {
        List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();


        if (response != null)
        {
            using (var db = new FMBDBPRDEntities1())
            {
                foreach (var aYear in response)
                {

                    List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                                           .Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                                           .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();

                    allPaths.AddRange(paths);
                }
            }
        }
        return allPaths; // or do whatever with your total results
    }
}
```

> I am trying to pass the allPaths to my controller:
>   **My Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] years, string[] months, string[]radio, string[] acctNum)
    {

        ClientStatement_Inventory theStatementPath = new ClientStatement_Inventory();
        var thePath = theStatementPath.statementPath;

        DBQueries getyears = new DBQueries();
        var allPaths = getyears.GetSpecificYears(years);

        var cd = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileNameStar = theStatementPath.statementPath
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(theStatementPath.statementPath, theStatementPath.statementPath);

    }
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're facing? You're calling the `GetSpecificYears(...)` method but not doing anything with it? What are the paths? Are the files stored in the database & what if so what format, PDF?

Comment: @StuartFrankish Yes they are PDF. I am sorry for not asking the question more correctly. I  changed my line of code from getyears.GetSpecificYears(years); to var allYears = getyears.GetSpecificYears(years);.. Now I am trying to download those files on that variable in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would just do that inside of your controller and you won't have to mess with that at all.

Comment: Thats exaactly what i ended up doing, Thank you.